# Chrome adds an entry to block all images since v17 upgrade?

Tags: google-chrome

I just upgraded Chrome to v17, and all of a sudden no images load anymore at *any* website. I was notified by an icon in the address bar with a link to the options screen. At the options page, there was an entry to block images on websites for which the host name matches `*` - so, basically all websites. I'm not able to remove this entry.

What I eventually did was adding two other entries: `http://*` and `https://*`, both set to "allow". Although images do show up now, I was wondering how I could remove the entries altogether. I don't understand why nothing happens when I click the `x` next to the `*` entry. (I don't understand why this entry has been added in the first place, either.)

This is a screenshot (Dutch version, Toestaan = Allow, Blokkeren = Block):

[image: Screenshot of options page]

Is anyone else experiencing this problem and how can it be solved?

How to remove the stubborn `*` entry? I also can't add one to override its behavior...

Comment: Superuser is not your chrome bugtracker.

Comment: @kinokihuf: The point is that I don't quite know how to reproduce it so filing a bug is not very helpful I guess. I was rather wondering whether there is someone else experiencing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to [create a new browser profile](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142059), which should reset this issue. I guess it imported something wrong from your previous profile, which is why the entry could be there...

Comment: I'm sorry but it does not allow me to do so. The new entry is not added whilst the old stays there.

Comment: @pimvdb: Updated my answer. See http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142059.

Comment: Thanks a million. Creating a new profile did the trick but when copying my settings etc back, the entry was there again (so the profile was indeed "corrupted"). What I eventually did was opening the `Preferences` file and removing all those image block entries myself (including the one corresponding to `*`). After doing so the problem was gone. Thanks again!